# How to make navbar responsive with flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I need help making it so when I shrink the width of my browser that it will be responsive and my **navbar links** will appear under my navbar title. Can someone help me out with trying to get this done.

I believe that I will need to use a flexbox to do this.  I've been trying a few different ways, but cant seem to get the links in `pagetitle` id and the `nav` id to appear vertically.

```css
html, body {  
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
}
body { 
  background-color: #AC876A; /* this is the turqoise color */
  color: black;  /* color of font */
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; /* no tail font is more readable for small font */
  font-size:16px;
}
#titleNav { /* titleNav is fixed, always at the top */
  /* position fixed removes the element from the normal flow, placing it where you specify with top/bottom, left/right */
  position:fixed; 
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index: 1;     /* To make sure titleNav is on top of content, give it a higher z-index than content                          (content would have default value of zero). */
  width: 100%;    
  background-color:rgb(71, 39, 14);
  padding-bottom: 10px; 
  /* height: 86px; /* NEW */
  color: burlywood;
  font-family: serif; 
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #68615D;
}
#pageTitle { /* no change */
  padding:12px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-size:48px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px; /* spaces out letters a bit */
}
#nav { /* fix the nav bar */
  position: fixed; 
  padding-right: 10rem;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  text-align:right;
  font-size:24px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-top:32px;
  overflow: hidden; /*when content to big to fit in area */
}
#nav a {  /* no change */
  text-decoration:none;  /* Do not want links in "nav" to be underlined */
  color: #C8C8C8; /* light gray: to provide color for links, you have to style the "a" tag */
  float: left;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}
#nav a:hover{
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
#nav a.active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
#content {  /* Added padding top and bottom to prevent top/bottom content from getting hidden under titleNav/footer */ 
  padding:12px;
  padding-top: 80px; /* prevent the top of the content from getting hidden under the fixed titleNav */
  padding-bottom: 40px; /* prevent the the bottom of the content from getting hidden under the fixed footer */
}
#footer { /* footer fixed, always at the bottom */
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  z-index: 1; /* make sure footer is on top of content which would have default z-index value of 0 */
  background-color:rgb(71, 39, 14);
  color: burlywood; 
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  padding:8px;         
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<!-- Use this type of comment within HTML -->
<title>U-Bin Moving</title>

<!-- this is your internal style sheet -->
<link href="style/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="titleNav">
    <div id="pageTitle">
        U-Bin Moving
    </div>   
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
        <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        <a href="blog.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <h2>The Right Moving Company For You</h2>
    <p>
        At U-Bin Storage we will get the job done for the lowest price. 
    </p>
    <p style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="pics/box.jpg" style="width:50%; border-radius:10px;">
    </p>
</div> <!-- content. [[Keep track of nesting]] -->

<div id="footer">
    [ Kyle Hrivnak ]
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated css file. Used flex box in the #titleNav and #nav.

```
    html, body {  
            margin:0; 
            padding:0; 
        }
    
        body { 
            background-color: #AC876A; /* this is the turqoise color */
            color: black;  /* color of font */
            font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; /* no tail font is more readable for small font */
            font-size:16px;
        }
    
        #titleNav { /* titleNav is fixed, always at the top */
    
            /* position fixed removes the element from the normal flow, placing it where you specify with top/bottom, left/right */
            position:fixed; 
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            z-index: 1;     
            width: 100vw;   
            background-color:rgb(71, 39, 14);
            padding-bottom: 10px; 
            /* height: 86px; /* NEW */
            color: burlywood;
            font-family: serif; 
            font-weight: bold;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #68615D;
          
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
         
       
        }
        
    
    
        #pageTitle { /* no change */
            padding:12px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            font-size:48px;
            letter-spacing: 1.5px; /* spaces out letters a bit */
        }
    
        #nav { /* fix the nav bar */
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            font-size:24px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            padding-top:32px;
         
        }
        
    
        
      
        #nav a {  /* no change */
            text-decoration:none;  /* Do not want links in "nav" to be underlined */
            color: #C8C8C8; /* light gray: to provide color for links, you have to style the "a" tag */
            float: left;
            padding-left: 16px;
            padding-right: 16px;
        
        }
        
        #nav a:hover{
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }
        
        #nav a.active{
            border-bottom: 2px solid black;
        }
    
        #content {  /* Added padding top and bottom to prevent top/bottom content from getting hidden under titleNav/footer */ 
    
            padding:12px;
            padding-top: 80px; /* prevent the top of the content from getting hidden under the fixed titleNav */
            padding-bottom: 40px; /* prevent the the bottom of the content from getting hidden under the fixed footer */
        }
    
        #footer { /* footer fixed, always at the bottom */
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px; 
            left: 0px; 
            z-index: 1; /* make sure footer is on top of content which would have default z-index value of 0 */
    
            background-color:rgb(71, 39, 14);
            color: burlywood; 
            width:100%;
            text-align:center;
            padding:8px;         
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look into `position: sticky;` which I think would work better for you example, but to keep it simple I stuck to just correcting your CSS...

Set #content `padding-top: 100px` or close to 100px and remove the positioning and padding from #nav so it looks like:

```
#nav {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 24px;
  overflow: hidden; /*when content to big to fit in area */
}
```

```css
html, body {  
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
}
body { 
  background-color: #AC876A; /* this is the turqoise color */
  color: black;  /* color of font */
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; /* no tail font is more readable for small font */
  font-size:16px;
}
#titleNav { /* titleNav is fixed, always at the top */
  /* position fixed removes the element from the normal flow, placing it where you specify with top/bottom, left/right */
  position:fixed; 
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index: 1;     /* To make sure titleNav is on top of content, give it a higher z-index than content                          (content would have default value of zero). */
  width: 100%;    
  background-color:rgb(71, 39, 14);
  padding-bottom: 10px; 
  /* height: 86px; /* NEW */
  color: burlywood;
  font-family: serif; 
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #68615D;
}
#pageTitle { /* no change */
  padding:12px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-size:48px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px; /* spaces out letters a bit */
}
#nav { 
  text-align:right;
  font-size:24px;
  overflow: hidden; /*when content to big to fit in area */
}
#nav a {  /* no change */
  text-decoration:none;  /* Do not want links in "nav" to be underlined */
  color: #C8C8C8; /* light gray: to provide color for links, you have to style the "a" tag */
  float: left;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}
#nav a:hover{
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
#nav a.active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
#content {  /* Added padding top and bottom to prevent top/bottom content from getting hidden under titleNav/footer */ 
  padding:12px;
  padding-top: 100px; /* prevent the top of the content from getting hidden under the fixed titleNav */
  padding-bottom: 40px; /* prevent the the bottom of the content from getting hidden under the fixed footer */
}
#footer { /* footer fixed, always at the bottom */
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  z-index: 1; /* make sure footer is on top of content which would have default z-index value of 0 */
  background-color:rgb(71, 39, 14);
  color: burlywood; 
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  padding:8px;         
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<!-- Use this type of comment within HTML -->
<title>U-Bin Moving</title>

<!-- this is your internal style sheet -->
<link href="style/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="titleNav">
    <div id="pageTitle">
        U-Bin Moving
    </div>   
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
        <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        <a href="blog.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <h2>The Right Moving Company For You</h2>
    <p>
        At U-Bin Storage we will get the job done for the lowest price. 
    </p>
    <p style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="pics/box.jpg" style="width:50%; border-radius:10px;">
    </p>
</div> <!-- content. [[Keep track of nesting]] -->

<div id="footer">
    [ Kyle Hrivnak ]
</div>
```